Android studio jetpack compose circular progress bar tracker with points like the starbucks loyalty program
i'm stuck on making a loyalty program feature like Starbucks using jetpack compose that you earn points based on what recycable materials you have given to the coffee shop, for example: 1cup is worth 2pts and etc... And after reaching a certain number points you can redeem rewards, for example: at 30pts you can redeem an  iced coffee. Help me pleaseee
I have no idea how to do this, this is the only feature on my app that I can't code

Sounds like problem you should post in freelancer .com

I think the best thing you are getting is
Box(){
   CircularProgressIndicator(
      getLoyalPoints // as a method
   )
   Text(
      "5 Points",
      modifier = Modifier
         .align(Alignment.Center)
   )
}

This will generate a CircularProgressIndicator with Text on the inside. I think this will get you closer, unfortunately its not possible to make a dotted one with the CircularProgressIndicator in native JetPack Compose.
The final design and styling is your thing.
This will make it look like:

Hope this helps!
